# Windows Live ID exists but Hotmail says it is incorrect

Tags: outlook.com

I have been trying to reset the lost password for my Hotmail email address on Windows Live. I am using the page https://account.live.com/password/reset , and it gives the following message:

> "The Windows Live ID is incorrect. Please try again."

after entering the email address. However, if I go to MySpace where I used the email and put it in the search for the user with the email address, my MySpace account comes up.

How can I log back in ?

Comment: Are you adding the correct domain after your username name (i.e. username@hotmail.com)?

Comment: It says they're using the email address

Answer (score 2):

Try testing it by sending an email to the email address from another email address. If you get a response that the email doesn't exist, you're basically able to login to myspace b/c myspace doesn't really check after the account was created.

The account could have been deleted if it hasn't been used over 90 days.